# Forcing Image to fill a Div in Angular regardless of aspect ratio

Tags: css, angular

I want to display a bunch of images stored on a server. The images are taken from a user's phone and the dimensions and aspect ratio are unknown.

I just want to have an image fully fill a DIV while maintaining its aspect ratio. If the image is wider than taller, I want the image scaled so the height is 100% the Div and the sides would be clipped off. Similarly for if the image is taller than wider, I want the image scaled up/down so the width is 100% of the Div

Hopefully this explains it
[image]

I thought this would be pretty trivial, but here i am. I can make an image fit tall or wide but not either depending on the aspect ratio. I've tried several different methods and I am at a loss.

I have a [Stackblitz Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scale-and-center-img?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimg-display%2Fimg-display.component.html).

I have a 2x2 grid, and I would like to get the images to fill those grids. Some images need to be rotated. I'm not sure why they need to be as the look normal on my computer. I have a hardcoded flag to force a rotation on some images, but the rotation appears to screw up the css further on.

CSS:

```
.img-container {
  /* height: 150px; */
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  /* height: -webkit-fill-available; */
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="showBorder img-container">
  <img #image class="container-img-objfit2" 
        [ngClass]="{rotateLeft: rotate}" 
        [src]="imageURL" />  

</div>
```

How can I fill these DIVs regardless of the aspect ratio?

*Can I do any of this inside angular? I tried to get the image size and see if I could set custom class that would handle the rotation, but that didn't seem to work either. The dimension for all my pictures was identical. So no way to distinguish which pictures need rotation.*

*Or am I going about this all wrong? Ultimately I think I will have a process to scale and crop the images on the server so they are prepared for the client app.*

**Update:**
[This sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scale-and-center-img-ximgc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimg-display%2Fimg-display.component.css) is an attempt to set the image in the background and use a :before selector to rotate the image. It does not work fully as I cannot change the image dynamically to other images.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the images as background-image for the div and set its size to cover.
So just remove the img tag and keep your div tag only

```
<div class="showBorder img-container" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + imageURL + ' )'">


</div>
```

In CSS you will have to specify the height and the size

```
  .img-container {
   height: 150px;
   width: 100%;
   background-size:cover;
  }
```

Comment: This does not solve the image rotating issue I have. 2 of those images need to be rotated and if I do that, this solution doesn't work. 

It got me thinking that I need to preprocess the image before your solution. I came up with [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scale-and-center-img-ximgc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimg-display%2Fimg-display.component.css) 

But I'm stuck here as I can't dynamically set the background image in the :before selector. But the rotation and scaling seem to work ok